# Upload and encrypt any file from google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, encryption, upload

I am making a small project for college in GAE (using Java) in which I implement a form of "messaging service" where when a user sends a message to another user, the message is encrypted by 128-bit AES using Java crypto libraries and then stored on the server. The resulting key then has to be entered by the recipient to be able to read the message.

I now want to **incorporate file upload (attachment)** capability in this. So that when a user attaches a file (which can be **ANY** file, jpg,gif,txt,pdf,doc,exe,etc...), it is first encrypted and then stored. I want to interpret any file like a txt file (a sequence of characters), so that encryption/decryption can be done by existing code. (Does this even make sense? I am thinking of this because you can open any file in notepad and see the file as a sequence of characters). I would like to keep a limit on size of attachment as something like 5-10 Mb, but if for some reason this can only be done for even smaller sizes (<1Mb) even then its fine with me.

So if a user attaches a file, say abc.exe, I interpret it as a txt file, abc.txt and encrypt it along with the message. Then when recipient enters the correct key, I decrypt the message and file abc.txt, but serve as abc.exe. (I can ask the user to first convert any file to .txt, but that would be awkward)

Can this be done? *And I am a novice to web development, servlets and GAE (my first project using any of these), so please bear with me.*

Thank You !!

Comment: Anything missing from my answer Shitij? Please followup on your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simple asnwer is yes: it can be done. The normal operation is to read the file as binary, encrypt the data, then base 64 encode it. Then the receiving side base 64 decodes it, decrypts it and probably writes the data. Base 64 will grow the data though, using 4 characters for every 3 bytes (+ maybe one or two padding bytes at the end).

If you need more information with it, such as the file name, you need to create some kind of container for the data and encrypt that. One solution is to use ASN.1 although that has a relatively large learning curve.

To view an example of this, take a look at the SMIME specifications and the CMS (cryptographic message syntax) which defines mail with encrypted attachments. CMS is broadly used. CMS is available in the bcmail (or subsequent) package of Bouncy Castle.

Note that you need some kind of authentication/integrity protection if you are creating an online protocol with encryption. A good PKI infrastructure may also be needed. This is a pretty large project to undertake.

Comment: Thanks for your reply owlstead !
Sorry for replying so late. For the project I had to submit to college, I dropped the idea of attachments because it seemed to be too difficult to do in the time I had. So  I forgot about this for a while.
But I want to follow up on the project in a few months probably, and I have very little idea of what you are talking about in that last post :P.  So I will read about these things and come back here after a few months (I am in the middle of a summer training right now) :)

Comment: OK, I will wait :P. Thanks for the response, even if it is a bit late.